# Unresolved external symbol linker error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, linker

I am not new to Visual Studio and I know there are many questions on this. But I really cannot figure this out. This is the error:

```
1>moc_displaycounter.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const Counter::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@Counter@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
1>moc_displaymanometer.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const ManoMeter::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@ManoMeter@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
1>moc_displaysvgmeter.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const SVGMeter::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@SVGMeter@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
```

So I did a dumpbin /EXPORTS on the import library and it returned this:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file analogwidgets.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  ??0AbstractMeter@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z (public: __cdecl AbstractMeter::AbstractMeter(class QWidget *))
                  ?staticMetaObject@Counter@@2UQMetaObject@@B (public: static struct QMetaObject const Counter::staticMetaObject)
                  ?staticMetaObject@Item@@2UQMetaObject@@B (public: static struct QMetaObject const Item::staticMetaObject)
                  ?staticMetaObject@Led@@2UQMetaObject@@B (public: static struct QMetaObject const Led::staticMetaObject)
                  ?staticMetaObject@ManoMeter@@2UQMetaObject@@B (public: static struct QMetaObject const ManoMeter::staticMetaObject)
                  ?staticMetaObject@PotentioMeter@@2UQMetaObject@@B (public: static struct QMetaObject const PotentioMeter::staticMetaObject)
                  ?staticMetaObject@SVGMeter@@2UQMetaObject@@B (public: static struct QMetaObject const SVGMeter::staticMetaObject)
```

I checked the exact signature on the import library. For a good measure, I used *depends* to check that these symbols were in the DLL (yes I know it doesn't play a part in the linking process, but just to ensure that the import library is not broken), but still it won't link. Tried with both debug and release x64 builds without success. Previously did not have problems with other versions of VS.

Any ideas on what I should do next?

Comment: Looks like you have forgotten to define some static class variables.

Comment: Unresolved external symbol errors occur when you declare something but forget to define it. Could be a member function or a static variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting static data from a DLL is a bit tricky.  The linker error says what you forgot to do, the classes are not declared __declspec(dllimport) when used in the client code.  Repro code:

Header.h:

```
#ifdef _USRDLL
#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORTED //__declspec(dllimport)       // <=== Problem here!
#endif

struct EXPORTED QMetaObject {
public:
    int foo;
};

class EXPORTED Counter {
public:
    static const QMetaObject staticMetaObject;
};
```

Source.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
const QMetaObject Counter::staticMetaObject;
```

Client.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{
    auto foo = Counter::staticMetaObject.foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Linker error:

> ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const Counter::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@Counter@@2UQMetaObject@@B)

Remove the // comment in Header.h to fix, the compiler now knows how to properly use a pointer to the DLL data.  Note how the original linker error told you about this problem.  If you now run Dumpbin.exe /exports on the library you can see that the exported member name changed to `__imp_?staticMetaObject@Counter@@2UQMetaObject@@B`.  Which is the pointer to the data.  A pointer is required because the data may be relocated if the DLL cannot be loaded at its preferred base address.